# Who offered a bounty for my question?

Tags: support, bounties

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615922/how-do-i-use-if-statements-to-check-the-text-of-a-page) and today I noticed that the best answer I gave received a +50. Why did he get that? I didn't see any bounties being offered there. I've never offered any bounties. If there were bounties offered, how would I know who offered it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza) did, see the [post revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21615922/revisions):

[image]

*Reward existing answer* means they wanted to give an extra reward to the answer. I guess that answer helped them a lot too!

Comment: Indeed it did! Uhm what does the "notice" do?

Comment: @puretppc: that's just the grey bar that announces the bounty being added and removed.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21615922/revisions) on the question and you'll see that the bounty was offered by [HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza) to reward an existing answer.