# How to know who offered bounty when revision history is not available?

Tags: discussion, edits, bounties, revisions-list

The answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234349/who-offered-a-bounty-for-my-question) explain that looking at revision history will show who offered bounties.

However what to do when no revision history is available? Like in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message), the first answer has been awarded a bounty but no revision history is available.

How to view the revision history or find out who offered bounty in such cases?

If bounty events are added to revision history, should there be a revision history even when the answer has not been edited even once since the beginning? Is that a bug?

Comment: I guess one way will be to edit the answer myself and then view the revision history, but that is a very bad reason to edit a post.

Comment: Relates [tag:feature-request]: [Show link to revision history when there are revisions but no edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168765/189976)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/112188/revisions

There's the link to that question's revision history. Even for a post that hasn't been edited you can take the question's ID from its URL, and throw it in that link (replace the ID that's there now) to pull up its revision page.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Didn't know that you can view the question revision in this case!

Comment: Is revision history the same as edited history?

Comment: @CRags Yeah, it shows non-edit statuses like bounties, so it's called the revision history.